# WPF window not closing

Tags: c#, wpf

could you tell a beginner why this small WPF-application is not closing as intended after the WorkflowTerminated event fires? The used workflow just terminates immediately. (using a WPF application, .Net Framework 3.5)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WorkflowRuntime wfRuntime = new WorkflowRuntime();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        wfRuntime.WorkflowTerminated += (se, ev) => this.Close(); // this doesn't close the window
        wfRuntime.WorkflowCompleted += (se, ev) => this.Close();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkflowInstance launcherWorkflow = wfRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(InstallerWorkflow));

        launcherWorkflow.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: When setting a breakpoint in the terminated-eventhandler, is it even executed?

Comment: Good question by the way, this haunted me before and was very hard to figure, +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because the callback is on another thread. A basic workaround is to terminate the application altogether using `Environment.Exit(1);`

To call the close function on the UI thread you should use:

```
wfRuntime.WorkflowTerminated += (se, ev) => {
    // call back to the window to do the UI-manipulation
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() 
    {
       this.Close();
    }));
};
```

Comment: My Application object doesn't have an exit() method. Propably because it is an WPF application? I tried Application.Current.Shutdown() which doesn't help. Still doesn't close...

Comment: How could I post the terminate event to the right thread (GUI thread)?

Comment: Environment.Exit() works, the application is closing. But it feels kind of dirty ;-) Is there a cleaner way, to reach my goal (i.e. handling the event in the right thread, so Close() works as intended?). Nevertheless thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Yep I updated the answer to callback the Close() method on the UI thread so UI windows closes right.

Comment: Just fixed a typo by the way (forgot the second closing parenthesis before semicolon)

Comment: Thanks Teoman. Now it works as intended. Looks kind of complicated right now though. At least for me as a beginner.

Comment: Yes updating the UI thread (main thread mostly) from a background tread is a bit complicating at first but is quite logical once you get the hand of threading.. Been there done that:)